# How do you disable a UIAlertAction depending on a UITextField in a UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

I'm using a `UIAlertController` to present the user with a dialog to enter a **5-digit CRN**. I want the `Add` button to be disabled until there are five and only five digits in the `UITextField`.

Here's what the UI looks like:

[image: A UIAlertController with a text field and two actions. The text field has seven digits entered into it, but the Add button is still disabled.]

Here are the properties that are set up for the `UIAlertController`:

```
var alertController: UIAlertController!

var addAlertAction: UIAlertAction! {
    return UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default)
}
```

Here's how I'm initializing them in the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add Class", message: "Input CRN", preferredStyle: .alert)
self.alertController.addAction(addAlertAction)
self.alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive))
self.alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
    textField.delegate = self
    textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
}
```

Here's how I'm trying to disable/enable the button using the `UITextFieldDelegate` method:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if ((textField.text?.characters.count)! == 5) {
        self.alertController.actions[0].isEnabled = true
    } else {
        self.alertController.actions[0].isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

However, the button remains disabled (or enabled) all the time. It never gets enabled. What's going wrong?

Comment: try using `textFieldDidBeginEditing`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Implement the logic in the `shouldChangeCharactersIn` delegate method of `UITextField`. This method gets fired on change in each character of textfield.
You can build the logic taking the range parameter into consideration.

Here is the code that works perfectly.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    
    if ((range.location == 4 && range.length == 0) || (range.location == 5 && range.length == 1)) {
        self.alertController.actions[0].isEnabled = true
    }else{
        self.alertController.actions[0].isEnabled = false
    }

    return true;
}
```

Tested successfully in `Swift 3`, `XCode 8` and `iOS 10`

Hope that helps.
Happy coding ...

Comment: For those trying to do more complicated text length validation (in my case I had min size and max size, had to account for inserting and copy/paste) the length of the new string: textField.text.count + string.count - range.length. Great answer but that was far simpler for me.

Answer (score 13):

Try using the textfield's EditingChanged event as follow:

```
let addAction:UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default)
addAction.isEnabled = false; //to make it disable while presenting

self.alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add Class", message: "Input CRN", preferredStyle: .alert)
self.alertController.addAction(addAction)
self.alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive))
self.alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
    textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
    textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.alertTextFieldDidChange(field:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
}
```

And the listener for text field should look like this:

```
func alertTextFieldDidChange(field: UITextField){
    let alertController:UIAlertController = self.presentedViewController as! UIAlertController;
    let textField :UITextField  = alertController.textFields![0];
    let addAction: UIAlertAction = alertController.actions[0];
    addAction.isEnabled = (textField.text?.characters.count)! >= 5;

}
```

Tested with Xcode 8 and swift 3. Worked for me.