# How to store text of alert in Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uitextfield, alert

I have a action sheet and I open a alert with them with the following codelins:

```
 func showActionSheet(postId: String) {
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Beitrag melden", comment: ""), style: .default, handler: { _ in
        self.alertBeitrageMelden(postId: postId)

    })
    actionSheet.addAction(action)
    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I now want to store the input of the textfield inside the alert in Firebase:

```
func alertBeitrageMelden(postId: String){
    // Create the action buttons for the alert.
    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Melden", style: .default) { (action) in

        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("gemeldeteBeitraege").child(postId)
        ref.setValue(["postId": postId, "reason": self.textFieldAlert])
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", style: .cancel) { (action) in
                                        // Respond to user selection of the action.
    }

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Beitrag melden", message: "Wieso möchtest du den Beitrag melden?", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = ""
        if textField.text?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
            self.textFieldAlert = textField.text!
        }
    }

    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    alert.addAction(defaultAction)


    self.present(alert, animated: true) {
    }
}
```

I don't get any data of the textField.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
if let te = alert.textFields?.first?.text , te.count > 0 { 
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("gemeldeteBeitraege").child(postId)
     ref.setValue(["postId": postId, "reason":te])
}
```

As this `self.textFieldAlert = textField.text!` will store an empty initial value , and move this line

```
 let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Beitrag melden", message: "Wieso möchtest du den Beitrag melden?", preferredStyle: .alert)
```

top of fucntion , so you can access it inside the alert action

---

```
func alertBeitrageMelden(postId: String) { 
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Beitrag melden", message: "Wieso möchtest du den Beitrag melden?", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Melden", style: .default) { (action) in

        if let te = alert.textFields?.first?.text , te.count > 0 {

            let ref = Database.database().reference().child("gemeldeteBeitraege").child(postId)
            ref.setValue(["postId": postId, "reason":te])
        }

    }) 
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", style: .cancel) { (action) in
        // Respond to user selection of the action.
    })

    alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = ""
    }
    self.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

You can also do this by keeping a reference to the alert's textfield

```
var alertTexf:UITextField! 
func alertBeitrageMelden(postId: String){

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Beitrag melden", message: "Wieso möchtest du den Beitrag melden?", preferredStyle: .alert) 
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Melden", style: .default) { (action) in

        if let te = self.alertTexf.text , te.count > 0 { 
            let ref = Database.database().reference().child("gemeldeteBeitraege").child(postId)
            ref.setValue(["postId": postId, "reason":te])
        } 
    }) 
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", style: .cancel) { (action) in
        // Respond to user selection of the action.
    }) 
    alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = ""
        self.alertTexf = textField
    }
    self.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works! One last question: How to enable the default action only if the user has put in some text?

Comment: set a delegate to the reference textfield and use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39538098/how-to-disable-uialertaction-depending-on-uitextfield-in-uialertcontroller , the key is `self.alertController.actions[0].isEnabled = true / false `

Answer (score 0):

You can get your `textField` from your `alertController` using `alert.textFields?.first`.

**Example:**

```
func alertBeitrageMelden(postId: String){
        // Create the action buttons for the alert.

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Beitrag melden", message: "Wieso möchtest du den Beitrag melden?", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = ""
        }

        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Melden", style: .default) { (action) in

            if let textFieldAlert = alert.textFields?.first?.text, textFieldAlert.count > 0 {

                let ref = Database.database().reference().child("gemeldeteBeitraege").child(postId)
                ref.setValue(["postId": postId, "reason": textFieldAlert])
            }
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Abbrechen", style: .cancel) { (action) in
            // Respond to user selection of the action.
        }

        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        alert.addAction(defaultAction)


        self.present(alert, animated: true) {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert.addTextField { textField in
}
```

This is alert's *configuration handler* where you can change properties of text field which will be added. But setting some text variable here doesn't make any sense because `text` of text field is empty in this moment.

Your goal should be get `text` of text field in moment when you need it, in this case in `UIAlertAction`'s `handler`

---

So create alert **before** you declare its actions and add text field

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Beitrag melden", message: "Wieso möchtest du den Beitrag melden?", preferredStyle: .alert)

alert.addTextField { textField in
    textField.placeholder = ""
}
```

then in default action check if text of this text field isn't empty and if isn't save this text to Firebase

```
let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Melden", style: .default) { _ in
    if let text = alert.textFields?.first?.text, !text.isEmpty {
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("gemeldeteBeitraege").child(postId)
        ref.setValue(["postId": postId, "reason": text])
    }
}
```